# is this not using boolean operators in c++?

Tags: c++

I have some code which is incorrect because i have not used boolean operators
However i thought the boolean operators in c++ were && and ||

here is the question:

> Enhance your search algorithm so that a query may contain
>   Boolean operators – AND and OR. For instance, a query “word1 AND word2” means to
>   find all the ideas, each of which contains both of the words. A query “word1 OR word2”
>   means to find all the ideas, each of which contains either word1 or word2.

and here is my code just for the and operator

```
void IdeaBank::AND_searchQuery(string search_word1, string search_word2){

vector <int> match_AND;
for (int i=0;i<newIdea.size();i++)
{ 
    if (newIdea[i].foundWordInBoth(search_word1) && newIdea[i].foundWordInBoth(search_word2))
        {
            match_AND.push_back(newIdea[i].getID());
        }   
}

}
```

i just changed the && symbol to || to check for the "or" part

is there something i am missing or am i not using the boolean operators correctly?

this is for my school project so my teacher was unable to give me any answers.

EDIT:
the function foundWordInBoth is a boolean function
and there is no error with the code.

i showed my teacher my code and he said no that way is too easy you need to use boolean operators, which is why im confused

i looked online and there were a few source codes that use boolean algebra where they assign boolean variables numbers.
could this be what he meant?

Edit: this was the response i got after sending an email

boolean expression not boolean operators. A boolean expression (formula) is a combination of boolean operators (AND, OR and NOT). Any formula in while statement or if statement is a boolean expression. Once you have functions for AND and OR, simply parse the expression and then combine the outcomes.
If have functions for AND and OR... is parse the expression to combine them into one function?

Can someone help explain?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Maybe you have defined the term "boolean operator" in your course in a sligthly different way than it's commonly used? Or did your teacher mean the actual `operator bool()` to convert an object to a `bool`? You probably have to ask your teacher for clarification.

Comment: It's understandable that your teacher cannot help you solve the problem but if he cannot even explain what the problem is then he's a useless teacher. I would try raising this issue with someone who has higher authority, get your parents to back you up. Your code seems fine to me. Obviously you have misunderstood something but it's not clear what.

Comment: If you're allowed to use this `foundWordInBoth` function then your code is perfectly okay. Of course it should actually return the result but other than that I don't see a problem and I don't see a way to add some 'more boolean formula'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EDIT: the function foundWordInBoth is a boolean function and there is
>   no error with the code.
>
> i showed my teacher my code and he said no that way is too easy you
>   need to use boolean operators, which is why im confused

Your code seems fine to me. Probably your teacher wants you to use the bitwise boolean operators `&` and `|` instead of the logical operators `&&` and `||`.

In that case `true & true = 1`, `true | false = 1` ...

Comment: How is that different from using &&? Because if both expressions return 1 it would still be true as in my orginal code

Comment: Yes they are. ```&&``` or ```||``` evaluates two expressions. Like ```(a == b) && (c >= d)```. In this case, as you can see, the two expressions evaluate to bools themselves. (Like in your code). ```&``` or ```|``` on the other hand work on bits. Example is at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/boolean/ (bottom of page)

Comment: But in my case i cant use bitwise and because i am comparing two logics and not integers?

Comment: you can.. ```true``` and ```false``` is internally 1 or 0 (for this case). ```(true & true == 1)``` will evaluate to ```true```. Similarly ```true & false == 0``` will evaluate to ```false```. I wouldn't recommend doing this outside the class you are taking though. :)

Comment: The teacher isn't talking about bitwise operators it seems but boolean ones. So OP was on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

If `foundWordInBoth` checks for the existence of a word and returns a boolean, then your code is correct.